# Enabling touch simulation moves an element to the right

Tags: html, css, firefox, touch, simulation

Whenever is choose a specific screen size an element on the right side of my header is where is must be,but whenever I enable touch simulation,it the proceeds to move the element more to the right and out of the viewable screen.I have tested this on my phone and it does the same thing of moving the element.

How can I stop the element and maybe other elements from moving whenever touch simulation is enabled?

I adjusted the position of the element to fit on whatever size screen below 992px.But when I enable touch simulation it then moves the element to the right and off screen.

Comment: Can you tell us what _exactly_ you do when you "enable touch simulation"? What software do you use? And it would also be helpful to see your CSS/HTML code. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). When we have those two things, we can reproduce your problem. In other words: Understand what the problem is. Perhaps then we can help you?

Comment: It is alot of code to post here.By enabling touch simulation,I mean that toggle you get whenever you preview the html file on your pc.When you press f12 and adjust the screen size based on device you can then enable touch simulation on the same bar.

Comment: OK, that's part of the browser developer tools. It probably doesn't matter, but it's nice to know which browser, on which OS, you're using. The link I gave you gives tips on how to minimize the code. Did you read it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.